# In Android RecyclerView while loading data from Firebase, I want to load admob banner ad at the same time

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am try some application using Android Studio, but I am not able to code load data from Firebase into RecyclerView at the same time I want to load Admob banner ad, I am able to load data from following code, but how I can load Admob banner ads?

I am tried many ways and watched many videos but that are only suitable for old type, not for new Firebase codes

CategoryViewHolder.java

```java
public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewTitle,textViewDescription;
    public ImageView imageViewNews;
    public View view;
    public AdView adView;


    public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        // normal click listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        // for long click listener
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemLongClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
        });

        textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        imageViewNews = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewNews);

        adView = (AdView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    }


    private CategoryViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

    //interface to send callbacks
    public interface ClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view,int position);
        void onItemLongClick(View view,int position);
    }
    public void setOnClickListener(CategoryViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

}
```

CategoryItem.java

```java
public class CategoryItem {
    public String title,image,description;

    public CategoryItem(String title, String image, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public CategoryItem() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }



}
```

mainactivtiy.java

```java
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryItem>().
                setQuery(databaseReference,CategoryItem.class).build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem, CategoryViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CategoryItem model) {


                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageViewNews, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                        }
                    });
                    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
                    holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());

                holder.setOnClickListener(new CategoryViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                      //some code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                });


            }



            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

                View view,view1;

                if(test%4==0){
                    view1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_ads, viewGroup, false);
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    //adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    new CategoryViewHolder(view1).adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    //mylist.add("ads");
                }

                    view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_news, viewGroup, false);


                return new CategoryViewHolder(view);

            }
```

layout_ads.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

layout_news.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Title 1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pok_logo_banner"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhh" />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Inside of your OnCreate in MainActivity.java, maybe below this line:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

Comment: Bro,  already there this code, i want solution to load every 4rth one as admob banner in this code